# Dynamic Graph Generation without GD

Tags: php, graph, gd

I am working on a project that dynamically generates graphs using data from a MySQL database. Ideally I would like to do this in PHP, but my my school's server does not have GD libraries installed. Does anyone know of a method of dynamically generating graphs without using a graph library (such as [jpgraph](http://jpgraph.net/)) that depends on GD--perhaps I should resort to someone else's applet?

Thanks,

Colorado

EDIT: Specifically, I'm looking to generate scatter plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charts you could use: http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Comment: Thanks, this plotting package is great and very simple.

Answer (score 2):

You could invoke an external program such as [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/).

[Demo](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/scatter.html)

[image: Scatterplot demo]

Answer (score 2):

Since most modern browser support svg/canvas.  You could draw it with javascript on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

There are many flash based ([Open Flash Charts](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/)) and javascript-jquery ([jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/)) based charting modules. You can use one of them.